# How to upsert when the graph has 0 vertices?

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have an upsert query to insert vertices in the graph like this:

```
V().coalesce(
    __.V().hasLabel("Person").has(id, "ABC"), 
    __.addV(_a).property(id, "ABC")
).limit(1)
```

However, it doesn't work when the graph has 0 vertices to start with.

How can I adjust this query so that it will succeed when the graph is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [element existence](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence) pattern shown in the Gremlin recipes.  In your example it would be:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").has(id, "ABC").fold().coalesce(
    unfold()
    addV(_a).property(id, "ABC")
).limit(1)
```

The fold will ensure that there is at least one traverser.

Comment: wonderful thanks! i'm completely new to gremlin and learning the query language is a little mind bending. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a recipe, commonly recommended for this that uses the following formulation:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").has(id,"ABC").
      fold().
      coalesce(
        unfold(),
        addV("Person").property(id, "ABC"))
```

Given ID's are unique you can also just do:

```
g.V().has(id,"ABC").
      fold().
      coalesce(
        unfold(),
        addV("Person").property(id, "ABC"))
```